# Options for refreshing visible view controller after popping top view controller with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

A `UINavigationController` has two view controllers: `A` and `B`.

`A` is the root view controller. `B` gets pushed onto `A`.

The goal is to refresh `A`'s view only when `B` pops back to `A` and no other times.

Two options:

1. Refresh `A` inside of `viewDidAppear`. Downside: this may refresh
   `A` other times than when `B` pops back to `A`.
2. Implement a refresh function inside of `A`, and before popping,
   invoke this refresh function from `B`. Downside: requires iterating
   through view controllers to find `A` (or maintaining a reference to
   `A` inside `B`) and requires exposing the refresh function publicly.

Any other options? Ideally, `UINavigationController` would offer some kind of delegate function that gets called whenever `B` pops to reveal `A` again.

Comment: If you are going from A to B, then why don't you create your own delegate method to make that fire in A, when you pop from B ? Is there any difficulties ?

Comment: @Janmenjaya no difficulties. That's essentially option 2. Just wondering if there are other, even cleaner options.

Comment: But in option - 2, you mentioned you need to loop through the navigation stack to get the viewController!! but I think your class B is on the top of A, is n't it?? If so then you don't need to loop through. And yes if the gap between the class A and B is more, that is class B is not the nearest most top class of B, then you can use notification to communicate to the class B, as notification send the message to all controllers those are in navigation stack. Does it make sense ?

Comment: @Janmenjaya `maintaining a reference to A inside of B` covers the scenario you're describing. thanks for the comment though!